# I am trying to apply a function to a column of a DataFrame but get error of a loop with signature matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I am trying to run the following code:

```
def f(df):
    new = pd.Series(df)

    i = new.str.lower() \
        .str.replace('[^a-z\s]', '') \
        .str.split(expand=True) \
        .stack()

    # generate bigrams by concatenating unigram columns
    j = i + ' ' + i.shift(-1)
    digrams = []
    for k in j[:]:
        k=str(k)
        k = k.split(" ")
        s = "_".join(k)
        digrams.append(s)

    return pd.Series(digrams)

df = pd.read_csv("labeled_new.csv")

#vectorize documents
df["abstract_text_x"]=df["abstract_text_x"].apply(f)
```

So df is a DataFrame with several columns and rows, I am trying to apply function f to only a column, abstract_text_x of the dataframe. This column contains a text which is a strin format. The function f will create bigrams and join the words with "_". The function works, the problem is when I am trying to return the result of f to the dataframe. 
I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

What does that mean? 
How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That error emerges when your code is expecting an integer type but receives a string or something else instead. Try adding a str() type conversion to variable s when you append it to the digrams. Also ensure the data type of "abstract_text_x" is string and not an object or an array. Basically, just iterate through your data and check through your datatypes, you'll find something that doesn't match up.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem persists. Plus I don't understand if the code needs an integer or string type because at first, you say it is expecting an integer type and I have to change some variables to strings.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to concatenate strings separated by an underscore and push them out in a pandas series. If that is correct, that what you need to do is make sure everything you are putting into your bigrams is a string. You also need to make sure that the pandas series expects a string. So for example, running:
for i in df['abstract_text_x']:
    print(type(i))
would allow you to see the datatype for the series. If that type isn't a string, then it needs to be. If the type of variable 's' isn't a string, it needs to be, et cetera.

Comment: So I have checked and everything seems to be a string. I can't figure the mistake

Comment: Scatter some print statements in your function to print out messages that confirm your process is progressing as expected and as your data as it is being manipulated to view its form, see if anything is out of place. If nothing comes from that, I'm not sure how much more I can help without having a sample of your data to test the code on.